# Setting todays date (not time) as a variable for report builder from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I want to set todays date as a variable on my query

```
print CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103)
```

this shows me the date as I want to use it, so I would ideally like to declare @today and set it to the date shown above. I know that's probably not the correct way of going about it, and it is an amateur mistake, but if anyone could help would be great. basically I want to report on the date in report builder so need to declare it as a variable for the parameter in report builder 3.0

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(30)

SET @DATE = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103)

SELECT @DATE
```

Comment: thanks Kindly, makes perfect sense when you know how ;)